# Can a reasonably complex mobile app using Google Maps sdk be built without using map ids?

Tags: google-maps, mobile

Google Maps mobile SDK documentation claims that map loads are free if you don't use a map id. Are map ids required to build a reasonably sophisticated mobile app? Can you avoid paying for map loads by avoiding their use?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing

Answer (score 2):

A map id is not required for most features.

At this time, only [cloud based styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-customization-overview) of the basemap requires a map id. All other features do not.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So for all intents and purposes, the mobile SDK for Google Maps is free. Their pricing calculator looks ominously expensive, but they have a comment that says "Get mobile Dynamic Maps without Cloud-based maps styling at no cost". For someone that is evaluating usage for a free app that might have millions of map views, that's a big deal.